# Meaning of military terms in the game

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, military

The following dialogue is taken from the subtitles in the first-person shooter video game -- [Crysis Warhead](http://crysis.wikia.com/wiki/Crysis_Warhead):

> SIERRA 1: Command, Sierra lead, bearing 270, angels 7, target is 16
>   and closing.
>
> JTAC: Copy, Sierra lead. Be advised. We’re experiencing significant
>   radio interference. Suspect KPA music. (KPA: Korean People's Army; music: radio interference)
>
> SIERRA 1: Copy that. Beginning final approach.
>
> O’NEILL: Oh yeah. Finally get to see some action on this trip.
>
> SIERRA 1: **Fangs away**, Sierra 2. This is strictly hit and run. You
>   copy? (Sierra 2 is O’NEILL)
>
> O’NEILL: Yeah, I copy.
>
> JTAC: Sierra team, command. Be advised: Raptor will be your **ACM** on
>   this mission.
>
> O’NEILL: Raptor? I don’t suppose I have a choice in this, do I?
>
> PSYCHO: Fucking hell… I knew it, Sean O’Neill.
>
> JTAC: Sierra lead, **deploy seven**, over.
>
> SIERRA 1: Roger that.

I've checked [Multiservice tactical brevity code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiservice_tactical_brevity_code) and [Acronymfinder for Military and Government.](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Military-and-Government/ACM.html)

But these three bold phrases just fall outside them; I failed to google the terms out.

Help to explain these military phrases.

Comment: Dunno.  It sounds like it's elliptical for ***put your** fangs away*.

Comment: You mean don't fight em too hard? @snailboat

Comment: At last I dug it out: Airspace Coordinating Measures
-- Measures employed to facilitate the efficient use of airspace to accomplish missions and simultaneously provide safeguards for friendly forces. Also called ACMs. Source: Department of Defense Dictionary of Military and Associated Terms: As Amended Through April 2010

Comment: Fangs away - no doubt equivalent to 'bombs away' imho. A guess at 'deploy 7' is a direct reference to 'angels 7' i.e., 7 of something flying & nasty, please attack with them... The TLA [ACM], I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to hazard a guess on

> **Fangs away**, Sierra 2.

The sentence might mean

> Do not engage the enemy too thoroughly. Do not try to capture prisoners or equipment. Do not spend more time than is needed to make a single attack. Do not spend time trying to maximize the enemy's damage.

The allusion here is to an animal that might opt to sink its **fangs** deeply into the victim, ravaging the victim to the full extent, or might just make a single attack and then fall back. An animal *putting its fangs away* is an animal preparing for a *hit-and-run* attack, not an all-out assault.

The expression "put your fangs away" is used in the metaphorical sense in literature: [example](http://books.google.ru/books?id=EFEVf0wCjt8C&lpg=PT52&dq=fangs%20away&hl=ru&pg=PT52#v=onepage&q=fangs%20away&f=false). Here's another [example](http://books.google.ru/books?id=TFND0ReoaCYC&lpg=PA82&dq=fangs%20away&hl=ru&pg=PA82#v=onepage&q=fangs%20away&f=false):

> She **put away the fangs** for a change and gave me a sugary sweet smile as she stood up.

Answer (score 2):

So, I happened to be speaking with an actual JTAC in the US Army Rangers, and asked him about this passage. He said it was a mix of authentic and inauthentic language.

*Fangs away* is colorful talk, not something he'd expect to hear on a mission.

*angels 7*  = altitude 7000 feet

*target is 16 and closing* = target is 16 nautical miles away and getting closer

*ACM* he thought a mistake possibly for AMC

He did not know what *deploy seven* meant.

P.S. For a game with really authentic mission lingo and flight graphics, he recommended *DCS A10 Warthog*.